# overflowing to right side of page

Tags: html, css

when i add the photos and "yayın akışı" text its getting to right side of page just like the images

2.problem is: there is 3 big photos , behind these photos gray line part is not fit to page

ps:solved ; problem was in the search box so i deleted it

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jArx0.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN2Me.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3bGp.jpg

```css
.start{

    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 40.7vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
}
.image{
    width: 450px;
    overflow: hidden;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 9px;
}
.image img{
    width: 100%;
}
p{
    font-size: 17px;
    text-align: justify;
    line-height: 26px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
}

header{
  height: 90px;
  background: #2f3640;
}

.inner-width{
  max-width: 2000px;
  padding: 0 40px;
  margin: auto;
}

.logo{
  float: left;
  padding: 15px 0;
}

.logo img{
  height: 62px;
}


.navigation-menu{
  float: right;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 90px;
}

.navigation-menu a{
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #ddd;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 14px;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  transition: .3s linear;
}

.navigation-menu a:hover{
  background: #fff;
  color: #2f3640;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.navigation-menu i{
  margin-right: 8px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.home{
  color: #ff6b6b;
}

.about{
  color: #0abde3;
}

.works{
  color: #feca57;
}

.team{
  color: #5f27cd;
}

.contact{
  color: #1dd1a1;
}

.menu-toggle-btn{
  float: right;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 90px !important;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 26px;
  display: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menubar.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Alba</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.12.1/css/all.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
          <div class="inner-width">
            <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="images/AAAALBA_thumbnail.png" alt=""></a>
            <i class="menu-toggle-btn fas fa-bars"></i>
            <nav class="navigation-menu">
              <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-home home"></i> Anasayfa</a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-align-left about"></i> Hakkımızda</a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fab fa-buffer works"></i> Çalışmalar</a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-users team"></i> Yazarlar</a>
              <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-headset contact"></i> İletişim</a>
              <a href="sistemler/login.php"><i class="hesap"></i>Giriş Yap</a>
            </nav>
          </div>
    </header>
    <div class = "start">
      <div class = "image" >
       <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/">
       <img src = "images/1.jpg" alt = "">
       </a>
      </div>
      
      <div class = "image" >
       <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/">
       <img src = "images/2.jpg" alt = "">
       </a>
      </div>
      
      <div class = "image" >
       <a href = "https://www.youtube.com/">
       <img src = "images/3.jpg" alt = "">
       </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1. Please consider formatting your message.
2. Writing on the screenshots is very hard to read. 
3. Provide code examples that are relevant (in your opinion) to the problem, not the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `body{ width:100%; overflow-x: hidden;}` and you wont have that anymore.

And edit class `inner-width` to set `max-width: 100vw;` instead of 2000px;

Comment: That's sort of a sledge hammer approach. It would be better to solve the actual layout problem.

Comment: @isherwood the problem is in class: `inner-width` max-width with 2000px... no need to search 1year

Comment: Then that class should have a rule such as `max-width: 100vw`. Cutting off overflow altogether can be troublesome for other parts of a site.

Comment: I agree with you that is also something that should be done. I edited answer with that